# Webview in flutter that uses TLS

Tags: webview, flutter, stripe-payments

I am developing an app in flutter that uses a webview to display an html file with a Stripe card element. It's been working fine with the test key but when I recently exchanged the test key with a live key the card element is not shown anymore.

After asking about it on the Stripe IRC I was told it's because the webview needs to be using TLS for the live key card element to work.

So my question is, how can I create a webview in flutter that uses TLS? I am currently using the [webview_flutter plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter) so it would be great if it could work with that.

Comment: What URL are you passing to `WebView`? Does it start `https://...`?

Comment: @RichardHeap No, it's a local html file that is read as a String. I'm going to try and host the file online and then read it using https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by hosting the html file online and then importing it as `https://...`